# Java Properties class throwing NPE when loading XML file within servlet?

Tags: java, servlets, nullpointerexception

All,

I have decided to adopt the **java.util.Properties** class within my servlets to facilitate easier maintenance of configs.

I am using the poperties class function loadFromXML to fetch an XML file that contains denatured (XML compliant ) SQL queries that my servlet will then execute.

Using this code which works fine in normal CLI Java application:

```
// retrieve all queries from xml from classpath
    queries = new Properties();
    try
    {
        String path = getServletContext().getRealPath("/WEB-INF");
        System.out.println(path + "/queries.xml");
        queries.loadFromXML(MyServlet.class.getResourceAsStream(path + "/queries.xml"));
    }
    catch (IOException io)
    {
        io.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The output is a NULL Pointer Exception thrown by the loadFromXML method

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>           at java.util.Properties.loadFromXML(Properties.java:851)

The file exists as produced by the system out message in the web server logs.

> CORE3282: stdout: /u02/SunONE61060/testserver/myservlet/WEB-INF/queries.xml

I tried moving the XML file to the base directory where the Servlet class exists and call it from there but still the same NPE.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
MyServlet.class.getResourceAsStream(path + "/queries.xml")
```

This will return `null`. `.getResourceAsStream()` can only load from the classpath (for instance, `/com/foo/myclass/MyResource.xml`).

Since you have the absolute path of your resource, just use a standard `FileInputStream`, for instance.

Also: **close your stream after you are done with it**. Right now you don't: you have a resource leak. See the javadoc for `Closeable`.

Comment: How do I use that with my properties class though?

Comment: Something like `queries.loadFromXML(new FileInputStream(absolutePathHere))`

Answer (score 1):

It isn't valid to get a real path and then treat that as part of a resource path. It isn't. Make up your mind. Just do

```
getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/classes/.../queries.xml")
```

where the ... is the package of MyServlet, and put the resource file there.

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to load the resources from your classpath but are providing a real path.  These two are not the same.

When you are using

```
MyServlet.class.getResourceAsStream("queries.xml")
```

Then the classloader will attempt to load the class from whereever your `MyServlet.class` file is, so if the package is `my.pkg`, it will attempt to load it from `WEB-INF/classes/my/pkg/queries.xml`.

You can also put the queries into the root of your class hierarchy (`WEB-INF/classes/queries.xml`) and load it like so:

```
MyServlet.class.getResourceAsStream("/queries.xml")
```

Then it will expect the file in `WEB-INF/classes/queries.xml`.

Alternatively, if you want to leave the file where it is, just use the servlet context to get the input stream:

```
getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/queries.xml")
```